# How can I make this container responsive?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, vue.js, frontend

I am trying to make the container responsive, but while going through developer options and checking in responsive mode, the container did not get placed correctly. I have simply added the margins to the button of the colors on the left side of the container. I am attaching the code and screenshots for reference.

```css
.color_selector {
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  height: 516px;
  width: 59%;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.grey_btn {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-right: 800px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

.grey_btn:hover {
  border: 3px solid #5998f7;
}

.blue_btn {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
  margin-right: 800px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: #1f316b;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

.blue_btn:hover {
  border: 3px solid #5998f7;
}

.brown_btn {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
  margin-right: 800px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: #57191a;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

.brown_btn:hover {
  border: 3px solid #5998f7;
}

.white_btn {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
  margin-right: 800px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

.white_btn:hover {
  border: 3px solid #5998f7;
}
```

```html
<div class="color_selector">
  <button class="grey_btn"></button>
  <br></br>
  <button class="blue_btn"></button>
  <br></br>
  <button class="white_btn"></button>
  <br></br>
  <button class="brown_btn"></button>
</div>
```

How do i make it responsive, the buttons and the container?

Comment: Look into media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries and possibly viewport units https://www.sitepoint.com/css-viewport-units-quick-start/

Comment: & what exactly is "placed correctly" in your context?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, remove the `absolute` positioning on `.color_selector`. Then you can use a [**media query**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) to adjust the container size on smaller devices. See the example below.

```css
.color_selector {
  align-items: center;
  height: 516px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* sample media query */
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .color_selector {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.grey_btn {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-right: 800px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

.grey_btn:hover {
  border: 3px solid #5998f7;
}

.blue_btn {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
  margin-right: 800px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: #1f316b;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

.blue_btn:hover {
  border: 3px solid #5998f7;
}

.brown_btn {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
  margin-right: 800px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: #57191a;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

.brown_btn:hover {
  border: 3px solid #5998f7;
}

.white_btn {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
  margin-right: 800px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

.white_btn:hover {
  border: 3px solid #5998f7;
}
```

```html
<div class="color_selector">
  <button class="grey_btn"></button>
  <button class="blue_btn"></button>
  <button class="white_btn"></button>
  <button class="brown_btn"></button>
</div>
```